# High Order Derivative Using Maclaurin Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Use the Maclaurin series to solve the following:
$$
\frac{d^6}{dx^6}(x^4e^{x^2})
$$
I got about halfway through the problem before getting stuck. I am not sure how to solve it... Any advice? Also, sorry for my formatting mistakes, computer nube here. Feel free to correct them.

Please help! I'm really stuck, and I need an answer soon!

Comment: Where did you get up to when you were solving it? What was it that "stuck" you?

Comment: Basically, I multiplied x^4 by Maclaurin series of e^(x^2), then manipulated the terms a bit to get one summation. Then I took the first and second derivative of this summation to look for a pattern that would allow me to estimate the 6th derivative. This is where I got stuck. :(

Comment: I think your issue might be with your manipulation then. If you do not manipulate the terms then there is definitely a pattern!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I like this question. So I will tell you how to solve it without actually solving it for you. Because that would spoil the fun.

**Step 1:** Compute the Maclaurin series for $e^{x^2}$. Remember that the formula for a Maclaurin series is given by the following.
$$f(x)=f(0)+xf^{\prime}(0)+\frac{x^2}{2!}f^{\prime\prime}(0)+\frac{x^3}{3!}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)+\ldots$$
So let $f(x)=e^{x^2}$. Then $f^{\prime}(x)=2xe^{x^2}$ (why?), and $f^{\prime\prime}(x)=2xe^{x^2}+2e^{x^2}$. Continuing, you should realise that *not all of the terms are zero when you substitute in $x=0$*. You should also spot a pattern, which is that $f^n(x)=f^{n-1}(x)+2f^{n-2}(x)$. **EDIT:** As 7raiden7 has pointed out in the comments, it is much easier to recall the Maclaurin series for $e^z$ and then substitute in $z=x^2$. This will save you a good few minutes!

**Step 2:** Realise that $x^4e^{x^2}=x^4f(0)+x^5f^{\prime}(0)+\frac{x^6}{2!}f^{\prime\prime}(0)+\frac{x^7}{3!}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)+\ldots$

**Step 3:** Differentiate this new series six times, using the fact that its derivative is the sum of the derivative of the terms of the new series.

**Exercise:** Use your working to evaluate $\frac{d^{104}}{dy^{104}}(x^4e^{x^2})$.

Comment: You can also use the fact that $e^z=\sum_k\frac{x^k}{k!}$ and therefore $e^{x^2}=\sum_k\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}$, (given that the Taylor expansion is unique, and $z=x^2$).

Comment: @7raiden7 Ahh-clever!

Answer (score 0):

Expand the function as a series, then differentiate term by term, and try to identify the resulting series. Looking at the function to differentiate, you'll have to decompose into a sum of series of the form $x^k \mathrm{e}^{x^2}$.